# What do we call 'school work' in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I wonder what we call 'school work' in German?

For students, we say, for example : Videospiele beeinflussen meine Studien

What do we say for pupils ?
Videospiele beeinflussen meine schulischen Leistungen ?

Comment: To clarify, are you talking about, in general, time spent at home studying for school, including reading, homework exercises (*Aufgaben*) and reviewing notes? Why would it be different for students vs. pupils?

Comment: Yes right . Concerning your question : Because pupils don't say "ich studiere" when they're still at school and 'Studien' comes from Studium so that's why I concluded that Studien is only related to students and not pupils

Comment: Students would more likely say "mein Studium", rather than "meine Studien". Except if they speak about actual studies that they perform.

Comment: Ok and what do pupils say ?

Comment: In English, a pupil and a student are more or less the same thing. I know there is a distinction in German between a *Student* and a *Schüler*, but it's confusing when you try to carry that over into English. If you mean *Student* vs. *Schüler* then you should use the German words; they are not interchangeable with the English.

Comment: @RDBury "In _American_ English a pupil and a student are more or less the same thing".  That is not true in British English (at least to people of my generation - mid 60's).  "A student" is necessarily in tertiary education and has left school.  "A pupil" is in secondary or primary education and has not left school.  (There are exceptions in both directions of course.)

Comment: @Martin Bonner supports Monica: Thanks. I watch a lot of British TV but there are some differences I've never noticed. Come to think of it, "pupil" isn't used much in the US now anyway, just say "student" for any age.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ja, genau. Es kommt aber etwas darauf an, was genau gemeint ist:

Schüler gehen in die Schule und lernen dort. Videospiele können nach Meinung einiger sogenannter Experten deren schulische Leistungen negativ beeinflussen. Insbesondere könne das Erledigen der Hausaufgaben dadurch zu kurz kommen.

Studenten gehen zur Uni(versität) und lernen bzw. studieren dort. Videospiele können auch dort nach Meinung einiger "Experten" deren Leistungen negativ beeinflussen. Insbesondere werden ggf. während des Studiums fällige Studienleistungen sehr spät erst angefangen.

"schulische Leistungen" sind alle Leistungen von Schülern in der Schule oder auch für die Schule zuhause in Form von Hausaufgaben.

Comment: I see this answer has already been accepted, but while "schulische Leistungen" is certainly a correct and valid term, it is most likely *not* what a pupil would say. It is, after all, quite formal, and even carries a hint of legalese or Beamtendeutsch.